# whats the best way to check if my API connection is SSL using network monitoring tools?

Tags: monitoring, network-discovery

I have a Java based system and it is using an API for additional features, the API has a built-in SSL connection on you just have to enable it in the code, and I was able to enable it but I still want to make sure that it really is SSL. Is there anyway for me to check this using any network monitoring tools?

Comment: Question about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic. You should try to ask this on [so], the programmers site, where there are network-savvy programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Wireshark to capture some of the data and verify that the traffic uses TCP port 443.  If you capture the initial handshake, you can see the SSL negotiation taking place.

Comment: "seems the auto suggest for your name is not working', that was quick. I've heard of wireshark before and I'll give it a try. Any other software you have in mind? Thank you.